# F# why arrays are not scrambled in a different way when mapping a function to scramble each array in an array

Tags: arrays, .net, f#

I wrote a function to scramble an array and map an array of arrays to scramble each one different but they are scrambled the same way

```
let rand = System.Random()
let shuffle (rand : System.Random)(array :int[] ) =   let rng = new Random()   
                                                      let mutable n = array.Length       
                                                      while (n > 1) do
                                                          let k = rng.Next(n)  
                                                          n <- n - 1                    
                                                          let temp = array.[n]     
                                                          array.[n] <- array.[k]
                                                          array.[k] <- temp
                                                      array

let playsarray =  shuffle rand 
let scrambledarray =  Array.map (fun x -> playsarray x  )
let playsarra = fun (array : int[]) ->  array |> playsarray
let smallarray =  [1..10].ToArray()
let megaarray = Array.create 10 smallarray
let megarrayscrambled = megaarray |> scrambledarray
megarrayscrambled |> Seq.iter (fun y -> printfn "Ar: %A" y)
```

after running the code all the 10 arrays have the same order in the data ej

- Ar: [|5; 1; 7; 2; 8; 10; 6; 3; 9; 4|]
- Ar: [|5; 1; 7; 2; 8; 10; 6; 3; 9; 4|] and so on ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

First, your `shuffle` function takes a `rand` parameter but isn't actually using it: inside the function you create a new `System.Random` instance and use it instead of using the one passed in. The [docs for the `System.Random` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8) mention (in the examples) that the default constructor uses the current time as a seed, so if two `Random` objects are created in quick succession, they would have the same seed and thus produce the same values. To fix this problem, you just need to stop creating a new `Random` instance in your `shuffle` function and instead use the one passed in (I renamed it from `rand` to `rng` so that the rest of your code wouldn't need changing). Here's your `shuffle` function with that change made (and with much easier-to-read indentation: you don't have to start the first line of the function on the same line as the `=` sign; you can put it on the next line and just indent one indentation level, four spaces):

```
let shuffle (rng : System.Random) (array : int[]) =
    let mutable n = array.Length  // The number of items left to shuffle (loop invariant).
    while (n > 1) do
        let k = rng.Next(n)  // 0 <= k < n.
        n <- n - 1           // n is now the last pertinent index;
        let temp = array.[n] // swap array[n] with array[k] (does nothing if k == n).
        array.[n] <- array.[k]
        array.[k] <- temp
     array
```

**BUT** that won't solve your issues just yet, because you've also misunderstood how `Array.create` works. It creates an array of a given size, where each item in the array contains the value you passed in. I.e., every entry in your `megarrayscrambled` array contains a reference to the *same* `smallarray`. If you did `megarrayscrambled.[0].[0] <- 999` you'd see that this changed every one of the ten entries in `megarrayscrambled`, because they're the same array.

What you actually wanted was to use `Array.init`, not `Array.create`. `Array.init` takes a function and runs that function once per item it's creating in the array you're building. This means that if that function returns `[1..10].ToArray()`, then each time it's called it will return a *different* array, and you'll therefore get the results you expect. (By the way, you can create an array more simply by doing `[|1..10|]`, and that's what I'll use in the sample code below).

So just change your `let megaarray` line to:

```
let megaarray = Array.init 10 (fun _ -> [|1..10|])
```

and then you should see the results you were expecting.

BTW, one more little detail: in one line you have `Array.map (fun x -> playsarray x)`, but that is just equivalent to `Array.map playsarray`, which is a little simpler to read.